# Is the phrase "let's go harvest" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

I wonder if "let's go harvest" as a line in a song would be more fluent than "let's go harvesting" which sounds to me really heavy. What is your point about that?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: People are always saying ***Let's go eat***, but I never heard anyone say ***Let's go eating***. On the other hand, ***Let's go snowboard*** sounds pretty unlikely compared to ***Let's go snowboarding***. Personally I don't think I've ever heard anyone use ***harvest*** as an intransitive verb, so I can't guess which "camp" that one falls in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - When I thought of using *harvest* in an intransitive sense, the very first thing that came to my mind was [Ecclesiastes 3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes+3&version=NLT): "For everything there is a season, a time for every activity under heaven.  A time to be born and a time to die.  A time to plant and a time to harvest."

Answer (score 1):

> go harvest
>
> go and harvest
>
> go harvesting
>
> go to harvest

are all possible ways of saying essentially the same thing. The first two are more colloquial, and the first one is strongly American: I (British) wouldn't say it.

As well as varying in formality, they also vary in how much they imply a literal "going" before the harvesting. The first two do not necessarily imply this, the fourth one does, in my estimation. The third one is unclear on the point.

Comment: Out of curiosity -- sorry, *curiousity* -- what about something like "go *get*"?  Do the British say "go *and* get"?

Comment: @Andrew. Yes. I would never say "go get", but "go and get" is perfectly normal for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go can be used with either the bare infinitive (like a modal verb) or with a gerund in an imperative ("Go eat!" or "Let's go walk"). There isn't a huge difference in meaning between the two. Both effectively mean starting the action. In other cases, a gerund is possible or the infinitive with "to":

> I go to walk
>
> I go walking

Whereas,

> to go to run

A structure like this can specify a future action (relative to the tense of "to go") or it can specify the purpose of moving (e.g. "He went to read" could indicate the subject left for the purpose of reading").

Comment: Unless you can give a supporting example, I'm suspicious of that first sentence. It seems to me ***go harvest*** as two consecutive bare infinitives is only acceptable because they represent a cut-down version of *Let's go **and let's harvest***. If ***go*** appeared as a *conjugated* verb form, as in ***He went to eat***, you couldn't use a "bare" infinitive - ***to*** is required there.

Comment: You're right. I oversimplified. You can use go with a bare infinitive for an imperative "Go eat!" or for a cohortative "Let's go eat"

Comment: As @Colin points out, the bare infinitive after ***go*** in imperative / cohortative contexts seems strongly American (certainly in something like *Go figure!*, though I must say *Go f##k yourself!* sounds as British as breakfast tea to me). Per my first comment to the question itself though, I can't say anything particularly useful about OP's *exact* context, because so much turns on the specific verb being used intransitively. And since I'm not used to hearing ***harvest*** used like that, I don't know whether to treat it on a par with *Let's go [and] **eat*** or with *Let's go **fishing*.**

Comment: At least in my dialect (some variant of General American), Let's go <bare infinitive> and Let's go <gerund> seem fairly interchangeable for most verbs, but there might be a change in emphasis. In particular, I think the gerund version may be more common for motion actions (walking, running) then others (sing, read)

Comment: The more we talk about it here, the more I find myself getting interested in *which* verbs work better with the gerund than the infinitive. I'm not sure if [to mannequin]() counts as a valid verb - but I suspect that if it does, *Let's go mannequinning* would be considered acceptable. I think it may be more about "known / recognised activity", rather than "motion action", but the implicit "motion" in ***Let's go*** is probably relevant too.

Comment: You may be right, but I think there's also for some verbs either means roughly the same thing (Let's go walk vs let's go walking) whereas others the meaning seems different (Let's go sing vs let's go singing). The bare infinitive use can also mean "go" for the purpose of doing the activity whereas the gerund seems to mean doing the activity itself